# Using FabricJS With React-Native

Tags: android, reactjs, fabricjs, react-native

I have an application which is built on a ReactJS and uses FabricJS extensively. We plan to reuse a lot of code and build mobile apps using React-Native but I am not sure how we can integrate the FabricJS component into it.

The app is something like [https://www.my-wallsticker.de/wandtattoo-selber-gestalten/](https://www.my-wallsticker.de/wandtattoo-selber-gestalten/?)

I have found and used https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fabricjs but nothing available for React-Native.

What could be the solution?

Comment: Have you found any solution , I need to develop same canvas with text and image placing and editing in react native.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to use a WebView with canvas (or something like this library: https://github.com/iddan/react-native-canvas) in order to be able to render anything with FabricJS.