# How to integrate Fabric js with React native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fabricjs

i'm making an app for restaurant reservation and i made a fabric.js canvas that allows you to select a certain table, also the admin is capable of changing the tables and allocating them however i don't know how to integrate Fabric js with react native?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using FabricJS With React-Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032584/using-fabricjs-with-react-native)

Comment: Those answers are almost 2 years old.  I'd be interested to know if there are any fresh ideas...

Comment: @stever I would argue that merely looking for fresher ideas doesn't necessarily qualify for a clear problem statement.

Comment: I'm not going to argue.  @Jose Rojas flagged it as a possible dupe.  I pointed out that those answers might be (are) stale - and not a dupe.  If you see a "clear problem statement", that's off topic for this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is two years old but I thought I'd add an answer for anyone else who may be looking at integrating `fabric.js` with `react native` (as I currently am).

Unfortunately, as `fabric.js` depends on a DOM (Document Object Model) & BOM (Browser Object Model) being present, it'll only work in a node or web browser environment; as there isn't any implementation or polyfill in any existing react native canvas library for these global objects. You can read more information about this on [the following github issue.](https://github.com/iddan/react-native-canvas/issues/93)

Your other option is using a web view component to render a webpage, but the downside to this is that it doesn't offer quite the same experience as a native app.